# Microsoft DNS Server (Windows 2008) CNAME issue

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, cname-record

I am using the DNS role in Windows Server 2008 R2. I have my records set up correctly with the following CNAMEs:

{removed domain names for security}

Currently, only the 'wsp' cname works. All the records are identically set up. I have checked with a DNS checker, and the other two CNAMEs do not resolve to anything.

I have tried restarting the server, re-creating the forward lookup zone.

Can anyone see what is wrong?

'A' records work fine when set.

Comment: +1 for posting real domain names ;)

Comment: Only put the [dot]s in because I didn't want them crawled!!

Comment: -1 for removing the real domain names...  j/k :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a **separate zones** for both magento and mysql. Probably nameserver looks in those zones, and CNAME that you may have in the parent zone is ignored. Guess those zones exist by mistake.

```
dig @ns2.domain.co.uk mysql.domain.co.uk any
.......
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mysql.domain.co.uk.        IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mysql.domain.co.uk. 86400   IN  NS  ns1.domain.co.uk.
mysql.domain.co.uk. 86400   IN  NS  ns2.domain.co.uk.
mysql.domain.co.uk. 86400   IN  SOA ns1.domain.co.uk. hostmaster.mysql.domain.co.uk. 2011112309 3600 600 1209600 86400
mysql.domain.co.uk. 86400   IN  MX  10 mail.mysql.domain.co.uk.
mysql.domain.co.uk. 86400   IN  MX  21 mail2.mysql.domain.co.uk.
mysql.domain.co.uk. 86400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx -all"
```

Besides you have possibly wrong SOA record for domain.co.uk - it refers to non-existing eku1_websrv1.domain.co.uk. Maybe you meant to put there something like ns1.domain.co.uk.

```
domain.co.uk.       3600    IN  SOA eku1_websrv1.domain.co.uk. hostmaster.domain.co.uk. 16 900 600 86400 3600
```

Comment: [That latter `SOA` resource record is not as wrong as you state.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-soa-field-semantics.html#DynamicDNS)  It's contents are irrelevant to this question in any case.

Comment: Thanks! What tool did you use to do that?

Comment: dig (on linux, probably windows port exists too), but actually with nslookup you can do all the same

Comment: Thanks - Problem solved - WebsitePanel added those zones, didn't occur to me that it would affect it.